# Запустить Makefile под Windows

Tags: c, mingw, makefile, msys2

Мне необходимо запустить makefile для сборки программы, написанной на С (ее текст представлен на скрине). Я совсем не разбираюсь в вопросах отладки, компиляции, программирования в целом, мне просто нужна итоговая программка для своих расчетов. Я пыталась запустить makefile, читая аналогичные темы на форумах. Скачивала и устанавливала Mingw32, msys, прописывала пути в PATH, но каждый раз у меня ошибки. Запуск через командную строку выдает ошибку "make не является внутренней или внешней командой", либо ошибки с разными кодами, которые мне также не удалось устранить. Если кто-то сможет дать мне относительно подробную инструкцию, откуда и что можно скачать, чтоб все заработало, буду очень благодарна. Система x64, винда 10.
Upd: добавила скрин кода makefile, и программки, которые он должен собрать, как я понимаю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1 - скрина я не вижу, 2 - код приложите в виде кода

Comment: Начнём с того, что *Makefile* - это инструкция для программы *make*. На вашем  компе эта программа **не** установлена. О чём Вам недвусмысленно говорит система:  "make не является внутренней или внешней командой". Вторая проблема в том, что "мне просто нужна итоговая программка" - для какой ОС Вы рассчитываете получит программу? Ведь *Makefile* - это (скорее всего) инструкция для создания Linux программы. И даже получив её, Вы сможете запустить эту программу только под Linux. Это действительно то, что Вы хотите? Подозреваю - нет.

Comment: Ну и - что делать. Если Ваша программа на С написана без особых "выкрутасов" и привязки к особенностям Linux, то (скорее всего)особых проблем не будет: надо просто установить на Вашем компе любой виндовозный компилятор и с его помощью выполнить сборку программы. Для простоты, можно поставить обычный GCC. Как это  сделать, подробно описано тут: https://programforyou.ru/poleznoe/kak-ustanovit-gcc-dlya-windows

Comment: А что бы эксперты могли сказать Вам, как собрать эту программу под виндой, надо опубликовать исходный текст, но не самой программы, а Makefile. Откройте его в блокноте и откопипастите сюда.

Comment: Если программа чисто вычислительная, то есть достаточно высокая вероятность собрать ее и под windows. Раз у Вас не получилось с MSYS (мне этот вариант больше нравится), то попробуйте установить Cygwin. Это среда, почти полностью эмулирующая окружение Linux. У нее есть свой интерпретатор bash, есть пакетный менеджер (впрочем, у MSYS2 тоже это есть). После установки минимальной версии cygwin нужно установить этим пакетным менеджером все необходимые пакеты (вплоть до графической среды x11, если надо) и потом можно собирать Вашу программу. Запускать Вам ее, также, проще будет в этой среде.

Comment: Если установлен mingw, то надо запускать `mingw32-make`, а не просто make.

Comment: MSYS2 `pacman -S make`, потом идите через msys2 в папку где лежит makefile, и выполняйте `make`

Comment: Прикрепила и код, и программки. Итоговая программа сугубо вычислительная, и как меня уверили, должна работать под виндой. mingw32-make мне также не помогала - тоже не являлась внутренней или внешней командой. Спасибо всем за отклики!

Comment: Марина, я попробовал собрать эту Вашу программу. mingw32-make ее естественно не осилил, нужен полноценный make. Пошел в MSYS - там make отработал нормально, насколкьо смог. Но это не главное. В программе используется настолько древняя версия _Си_, что современные компиляторы не хотят ЭТО компилировать. Подозреваю, что нужен gcc версии этак 2.9 или даже древнее. Либо немного переписывать программу. И возможный выход: там где я нашел исходники Вашей программы добрый человек собрал ее с LCC и выложил [исполняемый файл](https://www.mmnt.net/db/0/0/aftp.cmdl.noaa.gov/user/john/idl/ccgcrv/lcc).

Comment: @Vladimir Не знаю, что у вас за компилятор, но gcc 8.1 из состава mingw-w64 успешно скомпилировал код всего с двумя варнингами: https://imgur.com/R4BGzPw

Comment: @Marina Если пишет, что mingw32-make не найдена, то у вас не прописан в PATH путь до mingw. Или какой-то не тот mingw установлен. Возьмите вот этот: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/

Comment: @zed, Компилятор mingw-w64  gcc 7.3.0 x32 -posix-sjlj. Обругал `#include <varargs.h>` и `errorexit()`. Я не говорил, что я не справился все это вылечить (мне было лень тратить время на то, что может никому и не надо), я просто привел слова моего компилятора, что он "так не играет". Вы взяли исходники программы с моей ссылки? Или просто нашли более свежую версию программы?

Comment: @Vladimir **попробуйте установить Cygwin** - может быть я чего-то не понял, но зачем устанавливать Cygwin для того, что бы собрать обычную С-шную программу для винды?!  Я давно не работал под виндой, но неужели же нет ни одного компилятора, для винды, который может превратить С программу в EXE-шник?!  Зачем нужен Cygwin ?

Comment: @Vladimir Взял по вашей ссылке, но из папки на уровень выше. Более новой версии найти не удалось.

Comment: @Sergey, "обычной сишной программой" прога стала гораздо позже, чем я написал тот комментарий. На тот момент вопрос был о работе команды make. В mingw родной make не является совместимым с GNU make и многие makefile он не осиливает. Заметьте, про прогу нам ничего не было известно (а Вы еще стали запугивать, что она под Linux и вообще не заведется под Win). И тут есть 3 варианта: 1) виртуалка с линухом (новичку-сложновато); 2) msys2 (у него корявый установщик-пути к gcc надо ручками изнутри прописывать) и cygwin - который я не люблю, но в котором все гораздо ближе к Unix и проще использовать.

Comment: @Vladimir А нет, соврал - у меня собрались сорцы вот по этой ссылке: https://www.mmnt.net/db/0/0/aftp.cmdl.noaa.gov/user/john/ccgcrv а то, что лежит по вашей, действительно не собирается. И там уже версия по-новее от 2008 года (против вашей, от 2003). А судя по скриншоту в вопросе, у Marina версия ещё новее - от 2015.

Comment: Огромное спасибо всем за отзывы, я даже не надеялась получить такую поддержку! Да, я увидела, что среди исходников уже есть и EXE-шник, но к тому моменту уже установила GCC, и все собралось!

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы установили GCC для винды, то в каталоге, где расположены исходные тексты программы просто выполните команду:

```
gcc -o ccgcrv -Wall -I./ ccgcrv.c dates.c export.c filter.c filtvar.c utils.c -lm
```

И будет Вам счастье :-)

Comment: Счастье действительно пришло! Спасибо!